# Find the residue at $z = 0$ of $\frac{1}{z+z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the residue at $z = 0$ of $\frac{1}{z+z^2}$. The answer is $1$.

Okay I have seen this done via poles and limits however, in the book I am reading, these ideas do not come about yet, so I have to do this a different way. The basic idea I got from reading the chapter was to find a Laurent series for this function, and then find my $b_{1}$ coefficient. When I did this though, I obtained a coefficient of $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a geometric series,

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z + z^2} &= \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1 - (-z)} \\
&= \frac{1}{z} \left(1 - z + z^2 - ... \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{z} - 1 + z - ...
\end{align}

The residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, which is $1$.

Comment: I know this is a late comment but I do have a quick question. When the question says find the residue at $z = 0$, what are we actually doing with that knowledge in the problem? For example at the top you work makes sense to me, but I dont know where we apply the fact that $z = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Using Cauchy's Formula and since $\;z+z^2=z(1+z)\implies z=0\;$ is a simple pole:

$$\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac1{z+1}=1$$